# sending email issue using php mail()

Tags: php

I am sending email using the below code

```
$to = "syedmohammadibrahim@gmail.com";
$subject = "New Registration";

$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>New User Registered</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>".$_POST["name"]."</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email</td>
<td>".$_POST["email"]."</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

I cannot receive emails with this. Any suggestion?
can you please point error in this code.
Please help me

Comment: is your program in local computer or live host

Comment: Email servers like Gmail and Outlook don't accept emails coming from private mailservers. This is to prevent abuse and spam. You can check your servers ip address here to check if your server is indeed being blocked: https://www.spamhaus.org/lookup/

Comment: its on a live server.

Comment: add your `$message` values into one line.